# how to define a trigger that gives id automatically when insert a new person?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

as I described on the title, I want to write a trigger that defines to add a new staff by all giving attributes except ID, I want to trigger generate and insert it automatically. How can I do that?

I've written a code like below in PL/SQL, but it's including the sequence and I couldn't find how can I get the current max ID of my staff with using the sequence, so could you please help me, with or without using the sequence?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE BEFORE_INSERTING START WITH 1000 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NEW_ID_BEFORE_INSERTING
BEFORE INSERT ON STAFF
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
:NEW.STAFF_ID := BEFORE_INSERTING.nextval;
END;
/
```

By the way, this code works fine but as you see it's starting from 1000.

Comment: What's the problem with using a sequence?

Comment: I have to get the current max ID to continue from, but I start with 1000 instead of the current max.
so is there any code that I can get the current max and continue to count by adding 1? hope my English is clear enough, sorry.

Comment: "*how can I get the current max ID*" - you don't need that. And it would not work properly in a multi-user environment anyway. Gaps in sequences are **irrelevant** there is absolutely no need to avoid them.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use something like the following to find the maximum value for STAFF_ID and then redefine the sequence based on that value:

```
DECLARE
  nMax_staff_id  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(STAFF_ID)
    INTO nMax_staff_id
    FROM STAFF;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE BEFORE_INSERTING';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE BEFORE_INSERTING START WITH ' ||
                    nMax_staff_id + 1 || ' INCREMENT BY 1';
END;
```

You only need to run the above once, just to get the sequence reset. After that the trigger will use the sequence to obtain each STAFF_ID value. Note that there are other ways to redefine a sequence's value, but here we'll do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work, which is to drop the sequence and then recreate it with the new starting value.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

in order to find the max STAFF_ID you need the below select:

```
select max(STAFF_ID) from STAFF;
```

Once you have the highest STAFF_ID you can re-create the sequence as desired.

In any case you can increment a sequence like so:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_name INCREMENT BY 1;
```

I hope that helps!

Please don't hesitate to leave a comment for any further clarifications.

Ted.

Answer (score 1):

Using the sequence guarantees uniqueness of STAFF_ID but does not guarantee no gaps in assigning STAFF_ID. You might end up with STAFF_ID like 100, 101, 103, 106..

First, get the max(STAFF_ID) while the system is not running. Something like

```
select max(staff_id) from staff;
```

Then, create the sequence to start from the max staff_id. Something like

```
create sequence staff_sequence start with <max_id> + 1 increment by 1 nocache;
```

"NOCACHE" minimizes the chance of having gaps in the staff_id assigned

After, use the trigger that you created to get the nextval from the seuqnece

Note the following:
- Once a sequence is invoked for nextval, that number dispatched cannot be returned to the sequnece
- Any cached sequence values will be lost if oracle database was shutdown

If your requirement is not to have gaps between staff_ids, then sequence might not be used.